# In vuepress how and where can I set the webpack devServer?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuepress

In vuepress, I want to do some config for webpack devServer like below:

```
module.exports = { //... devServer: { https: true } };
```

but I don't know where I can config it. Does anyone know it?

In ..vuepress\config.js, config as below, but it doesn;t work.

```
module.exports = { chainWebpack (config, isServer) { } }
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this configuration with `.vuepress/config.js`. There is two configuration for change webpack:

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: (config, isServer) => {
  },

  chainWebpack: (config, isServer) => {
  }
}
```

For more details you can read the documentation: https://vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: This doesn't work for devServer though. Seems it only can be used to config build pipeline webpack configurations.